# Check if a macro argument is a pointer or not

Tags: c, variables, pointers, macros, variable-types

Is there some "nice" way to check if a variable passed to a macro is a pointer? e.g.

```
#define IS_PTR(x) something
int a;
#if IS_PTR(a)
printf("a pointer we have\n");
#else
printf("not a pointer we have\n");
#endif
```

The idea is that this is not done run-time but compile-time, as in: we get different code depending on if the variable is a pointer or not. So I would like IS_PTR() to evaluate to some kind of constant expression in some way. Am I going about this idea all the wrong way?

Comment: @mbratch, modern C (AKA C11) has means to observe types, namely the new operator `_Generic`.

Comment: I've tried to clarify what i meant as i wasn't thinking of the possibility of trying to do this run time, hopefully it's more clear what i mean now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a complete answer to this by combining what @alx and @zneak have, and throwing in __builtin_choose_expr:

```
#define is_same_type(a, b)  __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))

#define is_pointer_or_array(p)  (__builtin_classify_type(p) == 5)

#define decay(p)  (&*__builtin_choose_expr(is_pointer_or_array(p), p, NULL))

#define is_pointer(p)  is_same_type(p, decay(p))
```

So, `__builtin_choose_expr(expr, a, b)` is equivalent to `expr ? a : b`, except that the types of `a` and `b` don't need to be compatible, and there are no conversions done.  In case the input is not a pointer nor an array, `NULL` will be of different type, so `is_pointer()` will evaluate to false.

If we use the demo supplied by @Netherwire with a few tweaks, we'll see that the above can't handle incomplete structs (compile error). Still, we get no false-positives while also not failing on non-pointers/arrays. I think this should be good enough for most use-cases.

Here's @Netherwire's demo, with a few modifications:

```
char c;
printf("c is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(c) ? "Yes" : "No");

unsigned long long ll;
printf("ll is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(ll) ? "Yes" : "No");

double d;
printf("d is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(d) ? "Yes" : "No");

unsigned char *cp;
printf("cp is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(cp) ? "Yes" : "No");

struct TM *tp;
printf("tp is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(tp) ? "Yes" : "No");
// printf("*tp is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(*tp) ? "Yes" : "No");  // error

char a[42];
printf("a is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(a) ? "Yes" : "No");

printf("1 is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer(1) ? "Yes" : "No");

printf("\"str\" is a pointer: %s\n", is_pointer("str") ? "Yes" : "No");
```

This outputs:

```
c is a pointer: No
ll is a pointer: No
d is a pointer: No
cp is a pointer: Yes
tp is a pointer: Yes
a is a pointer: No
1 is a pointer: No
"str" is a pointer: No
```

Huzzah! We have no false-positives, plus the defines were able to handle more than just arrays.

Comment: You don't really need an `UNREACHABLE_VAR`.  You can directly use `NULL` as a random pointer.

Comment: For improving readability, I suggest breaking that huge macro into smaller ones:

`#define is_same_type(a, b)  __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))`
`#define is_ptr_or_array(p)  (__builtin_classify_type(p) == 5)`
`#define decay(a)            (&*__builtin_choose_expr(is_ptr_or_array(a), a, NULL))`
`#define is_ptr_not_array(p) is_same_type(p, decay(p))`
`#define is_pointer(p)       (is_ptr_or_array(p) ? is_ptr_not_array(p) : false)`

Comment: You did a great job!

Comment: Breaking into smaller macros made me realize that you can simplify:
`#define is_same_type(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))`
`#define is_ptr_or_array(p) (__builtin_classify_type(p) == 5)` 
`#define decay(a)           (&*__builtin_choose_expr(is_ptr_or_array(a), a, NULL))`
`#define is_pointer(p)      is_same_type(p, decay(p))`

Comment: Yea, I appreciate you taking it even farther! I'm surprised you were able to get rid of the redundant __builtin_choose_expr, because I kept getting errors when attempting that. Definitely looks a lot cleaner now!

Answer (score 8):

On Clang and GCC, `__builtin_classify_type(P)` evaluates to 5 if `P` is an object with a pointer type.

Comment: It also evaluates to 5 if it is an array.  <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107348>

Answer (score 7):

It is certainly not observable through the preprocessor in `#if` as you imply in your question. The preprocessor knows nothing about types, only tokens and expressions that are constructed from them.

C11 has a new feature that lets you observe a particular pointer type, but not "pointerness" in general. E.g you could do something

```
#define IS_TOTOP(X) _Generic((X), default: 0, struct toto*: 1)
```

or if you'd want that the macro also works for arrays

```
#define IS_TOTOPA(X) _Generic((X)+0, default: 0, struct toto*: 1)
```

There are already some compilers around that implement this, namely clang, and for gcc and others you can already emulate that feature with some builtins, see [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr).

Comment: In that case, is there any other funky way to go about it during compile-time?

Answer (score 5):

I found a more or less `_Generic` solution of this problem.

**Warning**: May be triggered false-positive (see an example below).

```
#define __INTERNAL_CHECK_POINTER(x) _Generic((x),\
          int: 0,       unsigned int: 0,\
         long: 0,      unsigned long: 0,\
    long long: 0, unsigned long long: 0,\
        float: 0,             double: 0,\
  long double: 0,                       \
      default: 1)

/**
 * Determines whether the variable has likely a pointer type (but may be triggered false-positive)
 */
#define IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(x) ((sizeof(x) == sizeof(void*)) && __INTERNAL_CHECK_POINTER(x) ? 1 : 0)
```

Demo:

```
char c = 0;
printf("c is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(c) ? "Yes" : "No");

unsigned long long l = 0;
printf("l is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(l) ? "Yes" : "No");

double d = 0.0;
printf("d is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(d) ? "Yes" : "No");

unsigned char* cp = 0;
printf("cp is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(cp) ? "Yes" : "No");

struct tm* tp = 0;
printf("tp is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(tp) ? "Yes" : "No");

char ia[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
printf("ia is a pointer: %s\n", IS_LIKELY_A_POINTER(ia) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

This will output:

```
c is a pointer: No
l is a pointer: No
d is a pointer: No
cp is a pointer: Yes
tp is a pointer: Yes
ia is a pointer: Yes // false-positive!
```

If you (like me) are looking for some logging (to draw or not to draw a `*` for a particular variable) and you're not looking for fail-proof results, try this, it may help. Cheers!

**NOTE** that [it won't compile under MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981823/is-there-any-option-to-switch-between-c99-and-c11-c-standards-in-visual-studio); use gcc/clang/etc. instead or make your own fallback implementation using this condition:

```
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L)
    // use _Generic code
#else
    // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

NULL is pretty much the only thing you can look for.  There is no way to determine if something is a pointer.

Comment: @Mawg A pointer is a pointer. There's no way that it could be *not a pointer*.

Comment: I only mention because we just foudn a bug where something that most definitely was not a pointer was being cast to a pointer.  It had the value 3, which does not seem very pointer-ish.

Comment: @Mawg If `sizeof(thing) != sizeof(void*)`, then `thing` is definately ***NOT*** a pointer

Answer (score 1):

There is a way without false positives nor negatives, but compilation will break if the parameter is neither an array nor a pointer.

```
#define is_same_type(a, b)    __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))
/* Is a an array? */
#define is_array(a)             (!is_same_type((a), &(a)[0]))
/* Is p a pointer? */
#define is_pointer(p)           (!is_array(p))
```

It needs the GCC builtin [`__builtin_types_compatible_p()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Behaviour:

If p is an array, it will evaluate as 0;

Else if p is a pointer, it will evaluate as 1;

Else, compilation will break.