# How test if a value is (or is not) a valid pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

For a unit test of C dode, I want to ascertain that a value passed as a `void *` is, indeed, a valid pointer.

I don't think that I can prove that it *definitely* is a valid pointer, but how can I say that it *probably* is? Or definitely is *not*?

I am developing and unit testing on a 64 bit Intel processor, and the target is an ARM 9. I am not averse to assembler inserts.

- is there a minimum value for a valid pointer? `0x08` doesn't look very pointer-ish, wheras values above `0x1000000` do.
- must it be divisible by something (say 8)?
- can I say with 100% certainty that an odd number is **not** a valid pointer?

I don't need a flawless answer, just something to catch most errors.

---

[Update] I am considering looking at the link map, although that seems like overkill. The problem is occuring when casting to remove compiler wanrings.  Some system calls require a `char *` or `void *`, and csting to those is masking some coding errors.

Comment: What is the OS?

Comment: Both host & target are LInux, but why woould that matter?

Comment: If your function can take any input, you can't tell a thing. For every possible pointer address, there will be a possible integer raw data value. Then you can't even tell if it is "probably a pointer". So without knowing the nature of the function inputs, I don't think this question makes sense.

Comment: For linux, maybe you could look at `/proc/$PID/smaps` to see if the pointer address falls in the of the mapped ranges of virtual memory.

Comment: if this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19255148/c-macro-checking-if-a-variable-is-a-pointer-or-not

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563

Comment: Like Lundin said, there is no way to do this in general.  If you want to test such a thing, you need to do unit tests on the caller (i.e. test that all conditions for the caller to pass a valid pointer are met), not try to test within your function that a valid pointer has been passed.

Comment: What if you read 1 byte from the address and catch the signal the kernel throws and try to interpret it? That would sort out most of the invalid addresses.

Comment: You should ever set to NULL a pointer not valid. It is one of the first "rules" for good programming. Never leave a not initialized pointer around.

Comment: A `char*` pointing into the middle of a string can easily contain an odd address.

Comment: @Valentin Radu - that only works if the OS checks the access and signals the program.   That is certainly not guaranteed for all possible invalid pointers.