# Is there any option to switch between C99 and C11 C standards in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, c99, c11

I am new to Visual Studio Environment and I am using VS2017 Pro.
I wanted to write simple program in C and compiled with both `c99` and `c11` standards. In Visual Studio, I could only find compiler switches for C++ standards only.

How can we tell visual studio environment that we want to compile current code with `c99` and `c11` C standards.

[image: Compiler Switch]

[image: Standard Switch]

Comment: As far as I know, Visual Studio's C compiler doesn't fully support C99 or C11, so the question seems moot.

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh :( ... by the way thank you for the quick respond.. so then MSVC compiled with latest `C` standard by default?

Comment: For many purposes, MSVC only compiles with C90.  However, the version you're using has considerably better support for C99 than older versions of MSVC — but as I understand it, that support is still not complete.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the info, I am thinking, Why didn't they provide at least an option for `C` standard switch :|

Comment: You would have to ask Microsoft, but the impression I have is that they're not interested in tracking C standards, just C++ standards.  When there's a C++ feature that is also in a newer than C90 standard, they often add it to the C compiler mode as well at some point.

Comment: @MichaelBurr got the point thank you.

Comment: Can somebody make an answer? I think the question quite interesting and the comments together make a good answer. Also I like to get practically answered questions out of the list of unsanswered questions.

Comment: MSVC just [recently started supporting parts of c99](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27827416/1708801) and I have not heard about any support for C11. In general they support the latest they support with no way to specify a previous version of the standard. I believe they only recently allowed this for C++ due to breaking changes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The only 'modes' supported by Visual C++ are: `/std:c++14` mode for C++14 conformance (the default), `/std:c++17` mode for C++17 support which is not quite complete as of VS 2017 (15.6). There is also a `/std:c++latest` mode which at some future point will include things in C++20. All of these should be combined with  `/permissive-` for improved conformance.

To meet C++11 Standard Library conformance, Visual C++ has to support the C99 Standard Library, that's not the same thing as supporting C99 language conformance.

At some point to meet C++17 Standard Library requirements, Visual C++ will have to support the C11 Standard Library and again that's not the same thing as C11 language conformance.

See [C++ Standards Conformance from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-standards-conformance-from-microsoft/) and [C++11/14 STL Features, Fixes, And Breaking Changes In VS 2013](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c1114-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013/)

There is a comment thread in the post [MSVC: The best choice for Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-the-best-choice-for-windows/) where a Visual C++ project manager takes on the question of true 'C11' conformance.

> Hi Onur,
>
> C conformance is on our radar though we’re focusing on C++ conformance first.
> We did some work in VS 2013 on C conformance, though we didn’t publicize
> it a lot. That work included:
> – C99 _Bool
> – C99 compound literals
> – C99 designated initializers
> – C99 variable declarations
> We’re nearing the end of our C++ conformance work. One of the last items
> is a conforming preprocessor: a feature shared by C and C++. The
> preprocessor will mark the beginning of our C conformance push as well
> as the end of our C++98/11/14 conformance work.
>
> Andrew

**UPDATE:** VS 2019 (16.8) will include `/std:c11` and `/std:c17` standards switches. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/). Because the MSVC compiler does not support Variable-length Arrays (VLA) it does not claim C99 conformance. Note that these switches enable the new C99 preprocessor covered in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/announcing-full-support-for-a-c-c-conformant-preprocessor-in-msvc/).

VS 2019 (16.11) and VS 2022 also support `/std:c++20`. See [this post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-cpp20-and-the-std-cpp20-switch/).

Answer (score 15):

Visual Studio is mostly a C++ compiler. In "C mode", it follows an ancient C standard from 1990.

Around 2013-2015, they made some effort to support not the current, but the previous C standard from 1999 ("C99"), some 16 years after its release. However, the work to conform to this standard has not been completed.

I believe the compiler also supports a few selected features of the current C language ("C11") such as the optional bounds-checking library. This standard has been available for 7 years but is not fully supported.

So if you need a conforming C language compiler, you should look for other alternatives.

Comment: One reason why one might need a C compiler might be when programming against the Microsoft Windows API, which is written in C. So if you intend to do Windows programming, I would advise to pick a different compiler.

Comment: Ludin thank you for the information, Which C compiler you prefer? `Intel C` compiler, `GCC` or `Clang` on Windows 10 and Ubuntu/Raspbian?

Comment: @Dinithi GCC/Mingw and occasionally Embarcadero (which, like VS, is mostly a C++ compiler). I haven't used the others much.

Comment: I recently tried Embarcadero (Borland) C/ C++, kind of old school. :) I will go with GCC.

Comment: you can absolutely use the Windows API from C++. The headers all have `extern "C"` in them.