# How would I go about reversing a 2D array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

Let's say my array looks like this. The number of rows will always match the number of columns in this program.

```
[0] [1] [2]
[3] [4] [5]
[6] [7] [8]
```

I would need to turn this into the reversed form:

```
[2] [1] [0]
[5] [4] [3]
[8] [7] [6]
```

I know that multidimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays, which hopefully shortens the scale of my question to just reversing a 1D array, but I don't know how to apply that same idea to a 2D array. The size will not always be a 3 by 3 array, but again the rows and columns will always be the same number.

Comment: Is each individual array in your array a row or a column?

Comment: not sure what you mean but there is one 2D array that has rows and columns. in the post i did my best to visualize it. i edited my array format in the post just now to make it a little clearer as to what it looks like, but its a simple 2d array.

Comment: The rows don't interact with each other, so start with code to reverse a 1D array. Once you've posted that, it's easy to explain how to adapt the code to the 2D array.

Comment: that's called mirroring or flipping, not reversing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code, here n is the number of rows and m is the number of columns. Hopefully this will solve your problem. Happy coding!

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < m/2; j++) {
        int temp = arr[i][j];
        arr[i][j] = arr[i][m-j-1];
        arr[i][m-j-1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a function to reverse 2D array, then you can use a function declaration like this: `void reverse_2d_arr(int , int (*)[]);`

where,

```
void reverse_2d_arr(int size, int arr[size][size]) {
    int i = 0, j, k, temp;
    while(i < size) {
        j = 0;
        k = size - 1;
        while(j < k) {
            temp = arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][k];
            arr[i][k] = temp;
            k--;
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

and call it using, `reverse_2d_arr(3, arr);` where arr is your 2d array and 3 its size.

Comment: I like the use of VLA, and making it handle non-square matrices is not hard.  I would use `for` loops, though, more like: `void reverse_2d_arr(int size, int arr[size][size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0, k = size - 1; j < k; j++, k--)
        {
            int temp = arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][k];
            arr[i][k] = temp;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Aside from VLA being optional for compiler support from C11 on. Most compilers will continue support.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Standard Arrays**

From an efficiency standpoint, swap two-elements per-iteration when iterating over the column values. Since your array has a fixed width, start with the beginning and end elements, swap them, and continue working from the end to the middle, e.g.

```
void rev2d (int (*a)[COLS], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0, k = cols - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
            int tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = tmp;
        }
}
```

(above the `..[j]` and `..[k]` elemnts are each swapped per-iteration of the inner-loop)

Or if you wanted to do the same thing using `while` loops and pointers to the beginning and end elements in each row (aside from iterating over the rows in reverse), you could do the following:

```
void rev2dptrs (int (*a)[COLS], int rows, int cols)
{
    while (rows--) {
        int *beg = *(a + rows), *end = *(a + rows) + cols - 1;
        while (end > beg) {
            int tmp = *beg;
            *beg++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

In each case, for example if you had:

```
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS ROWS
...
    int a[][COLS] = {{ 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }};
```

Your function call would be:

```
    rev2d (a, ROWS, COLS);
```

or in the second case:

```
    rev2dptrs (a, ROWS, COLS);
```

Just a twist on a normal reversal.

**Using Variable Length Arrays**

The original intent was to avoid examples with VLA due to [C11 Standard - 6.7.6.2 Array declarators(p4)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p4) `"Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support;"` and [C11 Standard - 6.10.8.3 Conditional feature macros](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.8.3) `__STDC_NO_VLA__`

However as pointed out in the comments, and with the real-world practicality that virtually all major compilers will continue to provide VLA, you can provide a bit more flexibility by reversing the declarations and specifying the `rows` and `cols` sizes fist and then passing the array as a VLA. The benefit is that it frees you from a constant size. For example, but functions can be re-written passing the array as a VLA:

```
void rev2dvla (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0, k = cols - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
            int tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = tmp;
        }
}
```

and with pointers:

```
void rev2dptrsvla (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols])
{
    while (rows--) {
        int *beg = *(a + rows),
            *end = *(a + rows) + cols - 1;
        while (end > beg) {
            int tmp = *beg;
            *beg++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the benefit is you are freed from the integer constant constraint on the number of elements per-row. By specifying the `rows` and `cols` parameters before the array parameter, the `rows` and `cols` values are known before the array `int a[rows][cols]` is specified as a parameter allowing the VLA to be a complete type.

The function calls would then be:

```
    rev2dvla (rows, COLS, a);
```

and

```
    rev2dptrsvla (rows, COLS, a);
```

If you understand each of the ways and how they differ from the others -- then you have sorting a 2D array under control. Let me know if you have further questions.

Putting the full example together to exercise each function above at least once and adding a print2D function, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLS 3

void rev2d (int (*a)[COLS], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0, k = cols - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
            int tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = tmp;
        }
}

void rev2dptrs (int (*a)[COLS], int rows, int cols)
{
    while (rows--) {
        int *beg = *(a + rows),
            *end = *(a + rows) + cols - 1;
        while (end > beg) {
            int tmp = *beg;
            *beg++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}

void rev2dvla (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0, k = cols - 1; j < k; j++, k--) {
            int tmp = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = tmp;
        }
}

void rev2dptrsvla (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols])
{
    while (rows--) {
        int *beg = *(a + rows),
            *end = *(a + rows) + cols - 1;
        while (end > beg) {
            int tmp = *beg;
            *beg++ = *end;
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}

void prn2d (int (*a)[COLS], int rows, int cols)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            printf (" %2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int a[][COLS] = {{ 0, 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7, 8 }},
        rows = sizeof *a / sizeof **a;

    puts ("original:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print original */

    rev2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* reverse col values using indexes */
    puts ("\nreversed using indexes:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print reversed array */

    rev2dptrs (a, rows, COLS);      /* reverse reversed array to restore original */
    puts ("\nrestore original using pointers:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print original */

    rev2dptrs (a, rows, COLS);      /* reverse col values using pointers */
    puts ("\nreverse again using pointers:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print reversed array */

    rev2dvla (rows, COLS, a);       /* reverse col values restoring original */
    puts ("\nrestore original using VLA w/indexes:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print original */

    rev2dvla (rows, COLS, a);       /* reverse col values using indexes */
    puts ("\nreversed with VLA using indexes:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print reversed array */

    rev2dptrsvla (rows, COLS, a);   /* reverse reversed array to restore original */
    puts ("\nrestore original using VLA w/pointers:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print original */

    rev2dptrsvla (rows, COLS, a);   /* reverse col values using pointers */
    puts ("\nreverse again using VLA w/pointers:");
    prn2d (a, rows, COLS);          /* print reversed array */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/revarr2d
original:
  0  1  2
  3  4  5
  6  7  8

reversed using indexes:
  2  1  0
  5  4  3
  8  7  6

restore original using pointers:
  0  1  2
  3  4  5
  6  7  8

reverse again using pointers:
  2  1  0
  5  4  3
  8  7  6

restore original using VLA w/indexes:
  0  1  2
  3  4  5
  6  7  8

reversed with VLA using indexes:
  2  1  0
  5  4  3
  8  7  6

restore original using VLA w/pointers:
  0  1  2
  3  4  5
  6  7  8

reverse again using VLA w/pointers:
  2  1  0
  5  4  3
  8  7  6
```

Comment: If the array has a fixed width (`COLS`), why are you passing the width as a parameter (`cols`) and not using `COLS` in the code?

Comment: In case the arrays are allocated and the parameters passed from the caller. (yes, you can remove both `rows` and `cols` parameters and just rely on the `#define` values in the simple case), but just trying to make the functions generic.

Comment: If you want the function generic, then I'd suggest using `void rev2d (int rows, int cols, int a[rows][cols])` instead. Shouldn't affect the function body you've written.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but it would still leave me with `a` as a VLA -- which I intended to avoid. I guess I could add it with that note.

Comment: Does anyone know of a C compiler that both claims C11 (or C18) support and denies supporting VLAs by defining `__STDC_NO_VLA__`?  MSVC is unlikely to claim support for C11, I think, though it might be getting better on that.

Comment: As as VS2017 MS claims C11 support and allows a standard choice with `/STD`. Prior to VS2017 the only parts of C11 provided were those required to support C++11. I'll try to find the link that discussed this.

Comment: Here is the SO link I was thinking about [Is there any option to switch between C99 and C11 C standards in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981823/is-there-any-option-to-switch-between-c99-and-c11-c-standards-in-visual-studio)